# Install php 7 on mac with Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

Hi just got a new fresh mac and I want to use the last version of php7.

So I have instal php 7.1 with homebrew successfully. But the `php -v` command show that I have the 5.6 version witch is the default version installed on mac.

How can I target the new version of php installed with homebrew.

I have followed this tutorial to do it : https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/installing-php71-with-homebrew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your PATH environment variable to have `/usr/local/bin` at the start because that is where **homebrew** puts your installed binaries:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Put that in your login profile too, so it works on future logins.

You may also need to rehash with:

```
hash -r
```

which causes your shell to forget where commands are, so it has to search afresh.